# Spring boot decode POST request body

Tags: spring-boot, encode, spring-filter

I have a spring boot application which has some POST API's. Consumer of API's is doing UTF-8 encoding on json values. Below is example.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name" "ABCD XYZ"
}
```

When client send above request, I am receiving,

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name" "ABCD%20XYZ"
}
```

Please note "ABCD XYZ" is being replaced to "ABCD%20XYZ". Now I want to decode these values before it reaches my controller class. Is there a way where I can access this request body and change it by decoding values?

Answer (score 1):

The way your client sends data is... peculiar.

However, you can use `@JsonDeserialize(using = UrlEncodedDeserializer.class)` on top of your DTO's `name` property, where `UrlEncodedDeserializer` could be implemented as follows:

```
public class UrlEncodedDeserializerextends StdDeserializer<String> {

@Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return UrlEncoder.decode(jp.getValueAsString(), DefaultCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

}
```

If you want to decode all strings this way, you can register the serializer as part of a Jackson Module instead.

Comment: This definitely worked for me. However I am looking for a generic solution instead of adding @JsonDeserialize at every variable.

P.S. Upvoted as working solution.

Comment: The generic solution would be to register the deserializer in a Jackson module, as I pointed out in the answer. Just declare a `@Bean SimpleModule stringDecodeModule()` and add the deserializer to the module. It will then be aplied to all strings.